# Polyline is drawn wrong position on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am simulating painting as same as Paint app in Windows, but can select stroke after drawing.

I draw a polyline by dragging mouse to paint on canvas, but sometimes suddenly a very straight line is drawn.

I checked the point collection of polyline, it is correct.

```
private Polyline _drawingLine;
    private Ellipse _ellipse;

    private void CanvasDrawStudentScreen_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get point before mouse changes position
            Point position = new Point(e.GetPosition(CanvasDrawStudentScreen).X, e.GetPosition(CanvasDrawStudentScreen).Y);

            if (_ellipse == null)
            {
                _ellipse = new Ellipse()
                {
                    Width = 10,
                    Height = 10,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                };
                _ellipse.MouseDown += _ellipse_MouseDown;
                CanvasDrawStudentScreen.Children.Add(_ellipse);
            }

            Canvas.SetLeft(_ellipse, position.X - 5);
            Canvas.SetTop(_ellipse, position.Y - 5);

            // Get list point when mouse move
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                _drawingLine.Points.Add(new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(_ellipse) + 5, Canvas.GetTop(_ellipse) + 5));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void _ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get point
        System.Windows.Point startPosition = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrawStudentScreen);

        var points = new PointCollection
            {
                startPosition
            };

        // Draw at start position
        _drawingLine = new Polyline
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 10,
            Points = points,
        };

        CanvasDrawStudentScreen.Children.Add(_drawingLine);

        Mouse.Capture(_ellipse);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void CanvasDrawStudentScreen_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get point before mouse changes position
            var position = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrawStudentScreen);

            // Reset temporary drawn objects
            _drawingLine = null;
            _ellipse.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Could someone please explain me why this issue happened and guide me how to fix it?
[Polyline with wrong position on canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqC7k.png)

Comment: You should add minimal code and markup reproduces your issue. Have you considered using inkcanvas? Ink tends to remove wiggles you get when drawing with a mouse and will  give smoother curves. That's the approach I use for drawing in our map editor.

Comment: *"I draw a polyline by dragging mouse to paint on canvas"* - there is no way to help, unless you [edit] question and add sufficient code to look at. See [mcve].

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code, but it looks like you should set the Polyline's `StrokeLineJoin` property to `Round`.

Comment: @Andy, I posted my code. I also think about InkCanvas, but it has some limitations such as z-index when selecting to delete stroke, textbox, shapes or customizing adorner of selecting stroke. (Sorry for my English). Do you encounter these problems?

Comment: @Clemens, after I set StrokeLineJoin property, it seems work correctly. I need to test more. Thank you.

Comment: I translate each stroke into an object has a series of points after the user completes it. I end up with a series of viewmodels I can work with.  I can present a list of those and the user can select, increase/decrease z-index, delete, change properties etc as they like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid "spiky" vertices, set the Polyline's `StrokeLineJoin` to `Round` or `Bevel`:

```
_drawingLine = new Polyline
{
    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
    StrokeThickness = 10,
    StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
    Points = points,
};
```